# Getting null responce from Alexa skill using Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to make and alexa skill that reads an API that I have created . The API is working fine and returning

```
{
"_id": "5a4523104494060cf097c1ad",
"description": "Sprinting",
"date": "2017-12-29"
}
```

I have the following code

```
'getNext': function() {
    var url = '***API ADDRESS*** ';
    var text = "The session will be";

    https.get(url, function(response) {
        var body = '';

        response.on('data', function(x) {
            body += x;

        });
        console.log("a" + text);
        response.on('end', function() {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);

            text += json.description;
            console.log("b" + text);
            this.emit(":tell", text);
        });
        console.log("c   " + text);
    });
    console.log("d" + text);

    // this.emit(":tell", text);
}
```

Which console outputs

```
2017-12-29T09:33:47.493Z        dThe session will be
2017-12-29T09:33:47.951Z        aThe session will be
2017-12-29T09:33:47.952Z        c   The session will be
2017-12-29T09:33:48.011Z        bThe session will beSprinting
```

However this is returning null for the this.emit function as it is.

If I comment that out and uncomment the other I get a 
     `<speak> The session will be</speak>` returned.

I think is something to do with scope but cant pin it down as to why the text is correct in log b but not in d. if I cant use this.emit in the resonoce.on('end') then I need a way of getting the information out of there to use at the very end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting stuck is because of asynchronous functions. `https.get` is an async function meaning that the code will go on executing and when https.get returns a response the callback function will be executed. Ideally, whatever you want to do with the response should be inside the callback function.

Your original value of text variable is `The session will be`. Then you execute the `https.get` and because its async, will move to executing other lines of code after `https.get` and execute `console.log("d" + text);` The value of text is still unchanged and prints the old value. Now the `https.get` returns a successful response and triggers the callback and now the text value is changed so `console.log("b" + text);` sees the new value